# Как правильно создавать и запускать "Кастомные" потоки в Spring

Tags: java, многопоточность, spring

Можно ли создать примерно такой Класс и запустить его таким образом в Spring

```
public class CustomThread extends Thread {


   @Override
   public void run() {
       while (true){
           System.out.println("I am "+ getName());
           try {
               Thread.sleep(200);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
       for (int i= 0;i<5;i++) new TestThread().start();
   }
}
```

Или нужно что-то дополнительно писать? (Или вообще этот способ плох?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если это обычная программа, использующая Spring для внедрения зависимостей, то можно. Для большего spring way можно объявить `CustomThread` бином и создавать не с помощью `new`, а получать из контекста. Это позволит внедрят в него всякое.

Хотя, лучше всё же использовать более современные абстракции из пакета [java.util.concurrent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) - `Executors` и `Futures`. Но это рекомендация не только для spring-программ, а для java-программ в целом.

Если же это web-приложение на Spring MVC или Spring Web Flux, то желательно использовать механизмы многопоточности этих фреймворков - [асинхронные методы](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-async), [события](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-events) и [реактивные потоки](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-reactor).